# How to add dynamically element to <thead>?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently struggling with a ( I suppose ) basic problem, and I can't find any answer about it.

I have a html table that can be printed on multiple pages.

The table have one title and 2 ( or more ) subtitle.

I've put the title inside a  tag, which is ok for the title : it prints on every single page.

But I can't have the subtitle changing dynamically : the first values have no subtitle, then I need to print a subtitle. This is what my table should look like :

```
<table>
    <thead style='display: table-header-group;'>
       <!--Here is my title with no subtitle-->
    </thead>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    ...
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <!--Here should be my subtitle that I need to repeat on every page after this point
        Title and subtitle n°1 should be on every page after this point.
    -->
    <tr><td></td></tr>        
    ...
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <!--Here should be my second subtitle. First subtitle should not be printed anymore
        Title and subtitle n°2 should be on every page after this point
    -->
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    ...
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I do that?

Thanks,

Sam

Edit : I've figured it out, by using multiple table. Still, I can't format column as I like, which is a minor problem but here is what it looks like now :

```
<table>
    <thead style='display: table-header-group;'>
       <!--Here is my title with no subtitle-->
    </thead>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    ...
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
    <thead style='display: table-header-group;'>
    <!--Here should be my subtitle that I need to repeat on every page after this point
        Title and subtitle n°1 should be on every page after this point.
    -->
    </thead>
    <tr><td></td></tr>        
    ...
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
    <thead style='display: table-header-group;'>
    <!--Here should be my second subtitle. First subtitle should not be printed anymore
        Title and subtitle n°2 should be on every page after this point
    -->
    </thead>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    ...
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Just now I need to format every td with same width, by taking the biggest width among all...

Comment: Its not clear. the text written in `td` will be printed.

Comment: Please edit your question and give more information. What do you mean by "dynamically"? Do you mean that you want to load a value from a database using PHP? Are you using a CMS like Wordpress? HTML is a static presentation language. It can not load data from any other source, you need to do that using for example PHP, Python, Ruby or any other suitable language.

Comment: I'm using python for loading value from database. But I'm not sure how this would help you.

I have a loop in which I print html. And at one point, I need to add a subtitle in my <thead> tag. The question is : How can I do that in JS? The value of my subtitle is not in database. It's just a label I want to add under my title.